On the role of observability in Linear Kalman filter
I'm attempting to persuade myself that a successful Kalman filter cannot be modeled by an unobservable linear system.
Is there a proof for this fact?
I tried looking at the Kalman filter's equation deduction, but I'm having trouble understanding how the observability hypothesis is involved.
Does anyone knows a reference or an hint for a proof of this fact?
I will apreciate any help, thank you.
Edited:
When I used the terms “it is possible to model” and “successful Klaman filter.” , I was referring to trying to understand what are the implications of designing a Kalman filter on an unobservable system. In particular, I was trying to understand whether on unobservable states, by running multiple simulations (e.g., motecarlo) the model contiunues to effectively predict covariance propagation and remains bias-free (as well as all other statistical proiprieties of the filter).

Please edit your question to define what you mean by "successful Kalman filter", and what you mean by modeling a Kalman filter by an unobservable linear system.  Do you mean that you cannot successfully construct a Kalman filter from an unobservable linear system?

If you're asking if one can construct a Kalman filter to observe the states of a non-observable system -- no.  No, you can't observe the unobservable.
Why you cannot do this is because, by definition observability is a measure of whether a system exposes information about all of its states in successive measurements.
This is why the classic test of observability is to find
$$\mathcal O = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf H_k \\
\mathbf {H_{k-1}\,F_{k-1}} \\
\mathbf {H_{k-2}\,F_{k-2}^2} \\
\mathbf {H_{k-3}\,F_{k-3}^3} \\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix} \tag 1$$
and determine whether $\mathcal O$ has a rank equal to the number of states.  If it doesn't (and if, in the case of time-varying systems, there is no $k$ for which it can), then the full space of the starting state is not accessible.
This rule applies to any observer, not just the Kalman filter.
You can find this in the equations for the Kalman filter update:
$$\mathbf S_k = \mathbf H_k \mathbf P_{k|k-1} \mathbf H_k^T + \mathbf R_k \tag 2$$
$$\mathbf K_k = \mathbf P_{k|k-1} \mathbf H_k^T \mathbf S_k^{-1} \tag 3$$
$$\mathbf {\hat x}_{k|k} = \mathbf {\hat x}_{k|k-1} + \mathbf K_k \mathbf {\tilde y}_k \tag 4$$
At each update (4), $\mathbf {\hat x}_{k|k-1}$ is only "pushed" in a direction that's in the non-null subspace of $\mathbf K_k$.  This, in turn, is in the subspace of $\mathbf H_k$, because of (3).  Unless the various $\mathbf F_k$ are such to rotate the entire space of $\mathbf x_1$ over time such that it all, at some point or another, falls within the subspace of $\mathbf H_k$, then that particular subspace can't be affected in $\hat {\mathbf x}$ -- and that means it can't be observed.

Is there any way to tell which filter states and which part of them were observed at instant k?

I doesn't work that way.  Unless $\mathbf H$ is full rank, at each sampling instant the measurement is some linear combination of the current states, and for a system $\mathbf F \ne \mathbf I$ each state vector is a linear combination of past values of the state vector.

What does it means "I doesn't work that way"?

It means I meant to say "It doesn't work that way", at least not in general.

The definition of observability from a nearby textbook: A continuous-time system is observable if for any initial state x(0) and any final time t > 0 the initial state x(0) can be uniquely determined by knowledge of the input u(tau) and output y(tau) for all tau in [0, t]. (The definition for discrete time systems is almost exactly the same). Less formally, a system is observable if you can uniquely determine the initial state given the measurements and control inputs.
Consider a system with two states: the position and velocity of a point along an axis. The system includes measurements of velocity, but no measurements of position. The system is not observable, since no amount of measurements or knowledge of control inputs will ever tell you the initial position. You could formalize this into a proof if you want, but I think the intuition is more helpful.
I don't really know what you are thinking of when you say "successful" Kalman Filter, but in the case I described, the filter won't be able to improve its estimate of the position state at all.

If the estimation's mean is the real state and the distribution's covariance is less than the covariance at the start of the procedure, I'll declare the filter successful. Although I can grasp the intuition, it's a little hard for me to formalize; it would be nice if you could provide further specifics.

The proof for the example system that I mentioned above is straightforward. Take the state x and covariance P and apply the Kalman filter update step with H = [0 1] and prove to yourself that the estimate and covariance of the position state will remain unchanged.

As for proving the same thing for a general system, I don't remember exactly. There is some proof that you can construct with the observability Grammian, but I can't remember the method of the proof and I can't find the relevant textbook.
